# Print random numbers in array size 20 and print number in lndex number

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers, location

Question:

Write a program to create an array of size 20 to store integers. Then, the program should generate and insert random numbers between 1 and 7, inclusive into the array. Next, the program should print the array as output.
A simple subset is part of an array that consists of a set of 4 elements next to each other. The program will generate a random number between 0 and 19, which represents the location in the array (i.e. index number).  Then, the program should print the 4 elements from that location. The program should take into consideration the boundaries of the array. There is no user input for this program.
 Your program must include, at least, the following methods:
- insertNumbers, which will take as input one integer array and store the random numbers in it. 
- computeLocation, which will generate the location random number and return it.

A sample run of the program is shown below:

Sample output #1:
Array:  2  7  4  3  1  5  7  2  3  6  2  7  1  3  2  4  5  3  2  6
Random position: 2
Subset:  4  3  1  5

Sample output #2:
Array:  2  7  4  3  1  5  7  2  3  6  2  7  1  3  2  4  5  3  2  6
Random position: 18
Subset:  2  6  2  7

What I have figured out so far:
  public class AssignmentQuestion3 {

```
public static int insertNumbers(int n1,int n2)
{
    int min = n1;
    int max = n2;        
    int randomNumber = min + (int) (Math.random() * (max-min)+1);
    return randomNumber;
}
public static int computeLocation(int l1,int l2)
{
    int min = l1;
    int max = l2;
    int computeLocation = min + (int) (Math.random() * (max-min) + 1);
    return computeLocation;
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
int array[] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

System.out.print("Arrays: ");
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int random1 = insertNumbers(1, 7);
    array[i] = random1;
    System.out.print(array[i]+ " ");
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow.com != DoMyHomeWorkForFree.com :P

Comment: I did a random number generator but am already stuck at that.

Comment: it kept on printing the arrays as the first number would be 0 then the rest of the 19 digits would be the same number .

Comment: Set an upper and lower limit in calculating the random number

Comment: Show us the code you've written so far, tell us what it does and what it should do.

Comment: okay I have realised what I did wrong for the random number generator . so far i have only able to print the 20 random numbers thats all. I am not able to show the codes that I have done because of the word limit in the comments section . I'll see if I am able to put it into the question

Comment: @Manu I have posted what I have done so far

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for calculating random numbers between 1 and 7 (inclusive) is wrong. It is actually computing random numbers between 2 and 7 (inclusive). You are only missing a parenthesis in your formula.

So this:

```
int randomNumber = min + (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + 1);
```

Should be this:

```
int randomNumber = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
```

Because multiplication is done before addition, your version actually equals this:

```
int randomNumber = min + (int) ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks to help you on your way:

A)

```
public static int insertNumbers(int n1,int n2)
{
    int min = n1;
    int max = n2;        
    int randomNumber = min + (int) (Math.random() * (max-min+1));
    return randomNumber;
}
```

This is a perfectly fine method to have, but it isn't `insertNumbers`. Rename it to `generateIntBetween` and use that as a helper function in your `insertNumbers`.

B)

In your assignment it says to create an `insertNumbers` that takes the entire array as an argument and fills it. I'm not going to write it for you but the header should look like this:

```
public static void insertNumbers (int[] array)
```

C)

```
int array[] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

does the same as

```
int array[] = new int[20];
```

or

```
int[] array = new int[20];
```

(I prefer the latter)

D)

looks like you're doing fine completing step 1 of the assignment.
Just continue... next step is to create a method 'computeLocation' and you could use your own `generateIntBetween` for that.